# Twilio PHP : getIterator

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am trying to retrieve call logs from twilio using twilio-php library. With the following code, I expect twilio to return last 10 records but it returns everything. I tried finding docs for this, but couldn't find it.

```
foreach ($client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 10, array(
    'To' => $_GET['callerid']
)) as $call){

}
```

Can anyone please help me how I can use the above code to display logs page wise. Like for 1st page it returns recent 1-10 logs. For second page 11-20 and so one.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Unfortunately there seems to be a known issue with the getIterator method that will make it return all the results regardless of the number of items you declare.

What it does however is iterate through all the results and make multiple requests to the API for each of the pages as [described here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/40).

What you can do however is use the [getPage](http://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/rest.html?highlight=getpage#Services_Twilio_ListResource::getPage) method, that will take a page number and number of records as such:

```
$callLog = $client->account->calls->getPage(0, 10, array(
    'StartTime>' => '2015-04-01',
    'StartTime<' => '2015-05-01'
));

var_dump($callLog->num_pages);

foreach ($callLog->getItems() as $call) {
    echo "From: {$call->from}\nTo: {$call->to}\nSid: {$call->sid}\n\n";
}
```

All you need to do then is change the page number (first argument on `getPage()`).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You guys should really update the docs since `getIterator()` is used in pretty much every example